# MS Access Reference Form by string variable

Tags: forms, ms-access, reference, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a combobox that obtains its rowsource from `MySysObjects` and shows a complete list of Forms in the DB.
A form name is selected from the combobox and passed to a function as a string,  using VBA (since  don't know how to convert that string to Form).
So, once the string value of the form is passed to the function I now have the string variable of the form I wish to do stuff to...
I would normally use:

```
Function MyFunction()
    Dim frmForm as Form
    Set frmForm = form("MyForm")
    DoCmd.OpenForm frmForm.Name, acDesign, , , , acHidden
    With frmForm
        Do stuff...
    End With
End Function
```

But!  As I have passed a string variable to the function - such as:

```
Function MyFunction(strFormName as String)
    Dim frmForm as Form
    Set frmForm = Form(strFormName)    'THIS DOESN'T WORK
    DoCmd.OpenForm frmForm.Name, acDesign, , , , acHidden
    With frmForm
        Do stuff...
    End With
End Function
```

My question is how do I use the `Set` statement to return a `Form` object?
I can either convert that combobox value on the form and pass a `Form` Object to the function or convert the combobox value to the function and convert it using `Set` or whatever is required.
I am hoping that it is a simple syntax question, but as I've tried everything I know, it must that elusive answer I have not tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems at this line:

```vb
Set frmForm = Form(strFormName)
```

First the collection's name is `Forms`, not `Form`.
And second is that `Forms` is the collection of forms which are currently open.  So `Forms(strFormName)` will throw an error if `strFormName` is not open at the time.

If you just do `DoCmd.OpenForm strFormName, acDesign, , , , acHidden`, the form will be opened in Design View and hidden regardless of whether or not it was already open.  And then you can do the `Set frmForm` without triggering an error.

```vb
Function MyFunction(strFormName As String)
    Dim frmForm As Form
    DoCmd.OpenForm strFormName, acDesign, , , , acHidden
    Set frmForm = Forms(strFormName)
    With frmForm
        'Do stuff...
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Yes, I see that I have made a couple of typos!!
I found it easier to just type freehand and obviously missed a few uppercase issues and missing letters (particularly an 's')!
Fundamentally, it was the ORDER of the Set part that I've known and read many times before (until a form is opened you can't Set anything!), but since 've never actually used it ever before, I chose to ignore a fundamental point!
Problem fixed!  And to think I spent several hours researching it too!  Once you know; you know!

Comment: And...

THANKS!
THANKS!